# How to add type definitions for module in subdirectory?

Tags: typescript, axios, nock

I am trying to mock requests made with [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) using [`nock`](https://github.com/nock/nock). This integration has some issues historically, but the workaround described [in this issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/305#issuecomment-272162405) works. My issue occurs when I introduce Typescript into the mix. While `axios` comes with type definition files for the main library, the `nock` and `axios` integration requires an import from a subdirectory like so:

```
import HttpAdapter from 'axios/lib/adapters/http';
```

The Typescript compiler complains about this line with the following error:

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'axios/lib/adapters/http'. 'C:/Users/<user>/<project>/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/axios` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'axios';`
```

How can I fix this error? I have tried various combinations of custom type definitions for `axios` resembling:

```
// <project>/src/types/axios.d.ts

declare module 'axios/lib/adapters/http` {
    import { Adapter } from 'axios';

    const HttpAdapter: Adapter;

    export default HttpAdapter;
}
```

I am not very experienced with Typescript, so my theories are that my custom definitions file is in the wrong place, uses the wrong module name, or is not exporting the correct thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

#### Additional Context

**Typescript Version:** 2.9.2

The (relevant) contents of `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017", "dom"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the types directory under the files/include like the rest of your TS files. Assuming all of the source files are in `src`, this should work:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017", "dom"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": true

    // This is automatically done by "moduleResolution": "node"
    // "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },

  // Also make sure to add any other directories as needed
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: Wat. I swear this wasn't working earlier, but now it does. Thanks. I have two projects that this problem applies to. Once I test it on my project at home, I'll mark this answer as accepted.